# Is there any way to access a AWS private bucket using nginx as a reverse proxy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, f5

I want to configure my nginx such that i can access my private bucket is there any way to do so? I know the s3 ip whitelisting method but I have to make my bucket public for that
is there any way i can make changes to my nginx config file ?

Comment: Is this in the context of using [NGINX as an object storage gateway](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-as-object-storage-gateway/)?

Comment: yes to cache my data

Comment: Did you read the link I sent you? It explains how to supply AWS credentials in the NGINX configuration file. Also, this solution appears to be a read-only gateway.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [S3 VPC endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/privatelink/vpc-endpoints-s3.html) and restrict access to the VPC running your nginx server(s). Your bucket and servers should be in the same region.

I'm not familiar with nginx options but it looks like you can expose objects [using the S3 API](https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-s3-gateway). Accessing the previous endpoint you will not exit the AWS network.

Comment: im running my nginx server on my localhost in the future i intend on migrating it to some other server not on a ec2 so i cannot use vpc right?

Comment: You can use a VPN connection so your localhost is part of the VPC. What is your target for the final deployment, ECS, EKS, Lightsail?